# Rejecting hash contents if they are not in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this array:

```
array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

I have this array of hashes:

```
ah = [
 {:id=>"1", :value=>"A"},
 {:id=>"2", :value=>"B"},
 {:id=>"3", :value=>"C"},
 {:id=>"4", :value=>"D"},
 {:id=>"5", :value=>"E"},
 {:id=>"6", :value=>"F"},
 {:id=>"7", :value=>"G"},
 {:id=>"8", :value=>"H"},
     ]
```

I need to reject any hash in `ah` whose id is not in `array`.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. I'd reconsider using that structure. Instead, build a simple hash with the `:id` values as keys with the associated `:value` values as the values. Then it'd be easy to use `ah.keys - array` to get the keys to be rejected. And it'd be extremely fast. But even faster at that point would be to use `ah.values_at(*values)` to extract just the values needed. This would break down if there could be duplicate keys, but allowing arrays of associated values would fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the inverse - the hashes whose id is in `array` by using this code:

```
ah.select{|el| array.include?(el[:id])}
```

If you prefer `reject`, you can use:

```
ah.reject{|el| !array.include?(el[:id])}
```

For more info: [Array#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject), [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select).
These methods create a new array, if you want to modify in place use [Array#reject!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) or [Array#select!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select-21).

Answer (score 4):

For big pieces of data I would go with some preprocessing to avoid `O(n*m)` lookups.

```
array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
array_hash = array.each_with_object({}){ |i, h| h[i] = true }
ah.select{ |obj| array_hash[obj[:id]] }
```

Comment: I was working on an alternative to the O(n^2) solutions but I really like yours.  I'm going to include it in my benchmark results if that's ok

Answer (score 4):

I realize there is already an accepted answer but since all the answers here are in `O(n*m)`, I thought I'd propose an alternative in O(n)*.

Here's a rough benchmark if the `ah` array has `100_000` items and we have `10_000` items in the sub array.  I'm including `fl00r`'s answer here and Cary's as we're all trying to avoid the `O(n*m)` scenario.

```
                                user     system      total        real
select with include        34.610000   0.110000  34.720000 ( 34.924679)
reject with include        34.320000   0.100000  34.420000 ( 34.611992)
group and select            0.170000   0.010000   0.180000 (  0.182358)
select by value             0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.041073)
select with set             0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.048331)
hashify then values         0.130000   0.010000   0.140000 (  0.139686)
```

The code to reproduce this:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

list_size = 100_000
sub_list_size = 10_000

ah = Array.new(list_size) { |i| { id: i, value: "A" } }

array = []
sub_list_size.times { array << (0..list_size).to_a.sample }

def group_than_select(ah, array)
  grouped = ah.group_by { |x| x[:id] }

  good_keys = grouped.keys - array
  good_keys.map { |i| grouped[i] }.flatten
end

def select_by_fl00r(ah, array)
  array_hash = array.each_with_object({}){ |i, h| h[i] = true }
  ah.select{ |obj| array_hash[obj[:id]] }
end

def select_with_set(ah, array)
  array_to_set = array.to_set
  ah.select { |h| array_to_set.include?(h[:id]) }
end

def hashify_then_values_at(ah, array)
  h = ah.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g) }
  h.values_at(*(h.keys & array))
end

Benchmark.bm(25) do |x|
  x.report("select with include") do
    ah.select{|el| array.include?(el[:id])}
  end
  x.report("reject with include") do
    ah.reject{|e| !array.include?(e[:id])}
  end
  x.report("group and select") do
    group_than_select(ah, array)
  end
  x.report("select by value") do
    select_by_fl00r(ah, array)
  end
  x.report("select with set") do
    select_with_set(ah, array)
  end
  x.report("hashify then values") do
    hashify_then_values_at(ah, array)
  end
end
```

- Hash maps are typically O(1) search though O(n) worst case is possible.

Comment: I recommend the [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem for benchmarks. It handles all the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution than rejecting those ids that are not in the array is to only accept the ones that do:

```
ah.select { |hash| array.include?(hash[:id]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more possibilities.

```
array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "99999999"]
```

**#1**

I expect the `include?` solutions would be considerably faster if `array` were first converted to a set:

```
require 'set'

def select_with_set(ah, array) 
  array_to_set = array.to_set
  ah.select { |h| array_to_set.include?(h[:id]) }
end

select_with_set(ah, array) 
  #=> [{:id=>"1", :value=>"A"}, {:id=>"2", :value=>"B"},
  #    {:id=>"3", :value=>"C"}, {:id=>"4", :value=>"D"}]
```

**#2**

If, as in the example, the hash elements of `ah` have distinct values for `:id`, one could do this:

```
def hashify_then_values_at(ah, array)    
  h = ah.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g) }
  h.values_at(*(h.keys & array))
end

hashify_then_values_at(ah, array)
  #=> [{:id=>"1", :value=>"A"}, {:id=>"2", :value=>"B"},
  #    {:id=>"3", :value=>"C"}, {:id=>"4", :value=>"D"}]
```

Comment: Converting to a set is a great idea and the benchmark for it is quite fast!